# Remove padding on Jetpack Compose Switch when Scaled

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to both scale and remove the padding around a switch composable and can't figure out why it's not working.

```kotlin
Row(
    modifier = modifier.then(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(2.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Yellow)
    ),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
) {
    Text(
        text,
        fontSize = 12.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .background(color = Color.Red)
    )
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
        Switch(
            checked = state,
            onCheckedChange = { onToggle() },
            modifier = Modifier
                .scale(0.5f)
                .padding(0.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Green)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what's the point of scaling and removing the paddings? I don't understand. Please share what you're trying to achieve... graphically speaking

Comment: I'm trying to remove the yellow above and below the red/green. The reason why is the app I'm designing is for a VR device and the minimum touch constraints don't need to apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `requiredSize` as below. Because when you use `scale` it just `resize` the `Switch` not the actual size.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
            Switch(
                checked = true,
                onCheckedChange = { },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .requiredSize(15.dp)
                    .scale(0.5f)
                    .background(color = Color.Green)
            )
        }
```